Prove the q-Vandermonde identity $\binom{m+n}{k}_{q} = \sum_{j} \binom{m}{k-j}_{q}\binom{n}{j}q^{(n-j)(k-j)}$ using q-commuting variables
I have seen a few questions on here surrounding the q-Vandermonde identity but in a different form. I've yet to find a proof that uses q-commuting variables. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to start the proof, or know where I can find a proof? Any help is appreciated!

Let $x,y$ be elements of a ring such that
$xy=qyx$. The connection with $q$-binomial coefficients is
$$
(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k_qx^ky^{n-k}.\tag1
$$
You can prove $(1)$ by induction on $n$, using the $q$-Pascal identity.
We then prove the $q$-Vandermonde identity by taking the equation
$$
(x+y)^{m+n}=(x+y)^m(x+y)^n,
$$
and extracting the coefficient of $x^ky^{m+n-k}$ from both sides. On the LHS, directly from $(1)$, the coefficient is $\binom{m+n}{k}$. Let us expand the RHS by applying $(1)$ to both $(x+y)^m$ and $(x+y)^n$:
$$
\begin{align}
(x+y)^m(x+y)^n
&=\left(\sum_{i=0}^m \binom mi_qx^iy^{m-i}\right)
\left(\sum_{j=0}^n \binom nj_qx^jy^{m-j}\right)
\\&= \sum_{i,j}\binom mi_q\binom nj_qx^iy^{m-i}\cdot x^jy^{n-j}
\\&= \sum_{i,j}\binom mi_q\binom nj_qq^{j(m-i)}x^{i+j}y^{(m-i)+(n-j)}
\end{align}
$$
In the last step, I am applying the identity $x^sy^t=q^{st}y^tx^s$, which is provable by induction from $xy=qyx$.
Finally, we determine the coefficient of $x^ky^{m+n-k}$ from that final sum. This coefficient is the sum of the contributions from all $(i,j)$ terms for which $x^{i+j}y^{(m-i)+(n-j)}=x^ky^{m+n-k}$, which is the set of $i,j$ for which $i+j=k$. That is,
$$
\binom{m+n}k_q
=[x^k](x+y)^m(x+y)^n
=\sum_{i+j=k}\binom mi_q\binom nj_q q^{j(m-i)}
=\sum_{i=0}^k \binom m{i}_q\binom n{k-i}_q q^{(k-i)(m-i)}
$$
This completes the proof (aside from the fact that I accidentally got $m$ and $n$ switched).
